# How to forward request from web1/servlet to web2/servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I've two web applications say web1 and web2. I want to forward a request from web1/servlet1 to web2/servlet2. Is it possible? Please help!

Comment: You may want to look at http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181 to see if you really should be using forward.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that i've to use forward as I have to send all parameters from the request. It works well in the same context but as the other servlet is in other application, so it's not being forwarded

Comment: You may want to look at ServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher as it is different than using ServletContext.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a two-step process:

1. Get hold of the `ServletContext` representing `web2`
2. Get the `RequestDispatcher` from that `ServletContext` corresponding to `servlet2`

So, something like this, from inside `servlet1`:

```
ServletContext web1 = getServletContext();
ServletContext web2 = web1.getContext("/web2");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = web2.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet2");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

There's a big caveat to all of this - the container may not be configured to permit cross-context forwarding, since it's a potential security risk. If this is the case, `getContext("web2")` will return `null`.

Comment: getwriter already used and outputstream already used etc? what to do?

Comment: @wasimbhalli: That's an unrelated problem to your question.

Comment: Sometime ago I've summed up cross context resource accessing (which can also be used as a base for request dispatching) in [this post](http://piotrnowicki.com/2011/01/accessing-web-application-resources-from-different-context/). It also includes exemplary configuration for Tomcat which allows you do such gnarly stuff.