# getRequestDispatcher() to another context

Tags: java, servlets

How to redirect `Request` object using `getRequestDispatcher()`, which located in another context?  Or how I  can redirect  data that stored inside `Request` object to another JSP? Mehod of HTTP protocol must be same (i.e. if initial method - POST, then i must redirect with POST. So `sendRedirect()` not applicable)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to forward request from web1/servlet to web2/servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889113/how-to-forward-request-from-web1-servlet-to-web2-servlet)

Comment: ok, but if I cant access to another servlet (to get him Context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is the way of setting the  data in the *Request* object .And getting the Value in the another page by using *request.getAttribute()* method.The sample code is :

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("newpage.jsp");
  request.setAttribute("msg","Welcome");
 rd.forward(request, response);
```

And It can also be  used with    *ServletContext*

```
  ServletContext context= getServletContext();
  RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/LoggedIn");
  rd.forward(request, response);
```

I dont think that the method type must same.Its an object of type Request and it can be accessed within the Context.And the difference between *SendRedirect* and  *Forward*  is that

In **forward**()

1. we pass request and response object so our old request object is present on new resource which is going to process our request.

2.It is **accessed within the same server** ,another resource could be any servlet, jsp page any kind of file.

In **sendRedirect()** :

1.client request to some other location,the new location is available on different server or different context.

2.It is **visible in browser as a new request** .It can also be called as the Client Redirect.

Comment: You are right It must be same type of method .either (GET,POST ) like that