# Code to get a Java servlet to act as a proxy?

Tags: java, http, servlets, web-applications, reverse-proxy

I have two Java web applications that have a single servlet that gets mapped to a specific URL:

```
red.war/
    WEB-INF/classes
        com.me.myorg.red.RedServlet (maps to http://red.example.com/doStuff)
blue.war/
    WEB-INF/classes
        com.me.myorg.blue.BlueServlet (maps to http://blue.example.com/doStuff)
```

I want to put these application (I'm calling them my "backend apps") behind a "proxy app" (servlet) that will decide which of these two apps will ultimately service a client-side request.

This proxy web app would take an incoming HTTP request, and determines which of the 2 "backend apps" (red or blue) to forward the request onto. The request would then be forwarded on to either `http://red.example.com/doStuff` (and then processed by `RedServlet#doGet(...)`) or `http://blue.example.com/doStuff` (and then processed by `BlueServlet#doGet(...)`). The returned response from the backend app (again, either `RedServlet#doGet(...)` or `BlueServlet#doGet(...)`) would then be returned to the proxy servlet, and ultimately returned to the client.

In other words, in pseudo-code:

```
public class ProxyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String forwardingAddress;
        if(shouldBeRed(request))
            forwardingAddress = "http://red.example.com/doStuff";
        else
            forwardingAddress = "http://blue.example.com/doStuff";

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        writer.write(getResponseFromBackend(forwardingAddress, request));
    }

    private String getResponseFromBackend(String addr, HttpServletRequest req) {
        // Somehow forward req to addr and get HTML response...
    }
}
```

**Is this possible?** If so, how and what code would I need to write to make it work?

Comment: We use [j2ep](http://j2ep.sourceforge.net/)...

Comment: You need to make an HTTP request to the backend server, take a look at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/index.html

Comment: I have tried https://github.com/dsmiley/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet and found it decent

Comment: Also have a look at HTTP-Proxy-Servlet issue #15 (https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet/issues/15) for a complete example.

Comment: See also [Reverse Proxy on Tomcat](https://serverfault.com/questions/433902/reverse-proxy-on-tomcat).

Answer (score 11):

You could use a `RequestDispatcher` to forward your request in the following way:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = httpRequest.getRequestDispatcher(forwardingAddress);

// here you have the choice whether to use include(..) or forward(..) see below
if(useInclude)
    dispatcher.include(httpRequest, httpResponse);
else
    dispatcher.forward(httpRequest, httpResponse);
```

... where `useInlcude` is set to your choice with the following options:

- **include**
  This is probably what you want to do: Load the content from the `forwardingAdress` into your response.

  - This means you could even include multiple targets into a single response.
  - The client will not even realize this procedure nor does he need to be able to see the target document.
- **forward**
  Send a forward to the `forwardingAddress`. This will tell the client to submit a *new request* to the specified URL.

  - If you do it in a browser with developer tools, you will see a second request.
  - The client must be able to see and load the target URL.
  - You can only forward to a single target.

See, the following links, too:

- [RequestDispatcher javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)), especially for the notes:

  - **forward** should be called before the response has been committed to the client (before response body output has been flushed). If the response already has been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException. Uncommitted output in the response buffer is automatically cleared before the forward.
  - **include**: The request and response parameters must be either the same objects as were passed to the calling servlet's service method or be subclasses of the ServletRequestWrapper or ServletResponseWrapper classes that wrap them.
- [URLRewriteFilter example](https://github.com/ultimate/syncnapsis/blob/master/syncnapsis-core/syncnapsis-core-application-base/src/main/java/com/syncnapsis/web/URLRewriteFilter.java)
  although this example is implemented using a `Filter` instead of a `Servlet` the behavior is the same (Note: this example is part of a framework of mine and hence contains some overhead in the parent classes. Just have a look at the relevant section...)

Comment: I think this solution would only work when the "backend" servlets are deployed on the same application. Since the red and blue servlet are deployed in different hosts it might be imposible to obtain the Dispatcher of their Context. See more explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889113/how-to-forward-request-from-web1-servlet-to-web2-servlet

Comment: What you say about forward is wrong: "This will tell the client to submit a new request to the specified URL." it's not a sendRedirect command

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not yet an approved answer I try to write how I see the solution to this request use apache-http-commons library. In addition I suggest to add a flush on writer.

```
public class ProxyServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String forwardingAddress;
    if(shouldBeRed(request))
        forwardingAddress = "http://red.example.com/doStuff";
    else
        forwardingAddress = "http://blue.example.com/doStuff";

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    writer.write(getResponseFromBackend(forwardingAddress, request));
    **writer.flush();**
}

private String getResponseFromBackend(String addr, HttpServletRequest req) {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(url);
        client.executeMethod(method);
        String body=method.getResponseBodyAsString();
        return body;

}
```

}