# Cross Domain Ajax Request to Spring MVC Controller fails with 302 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

For a Proof of concept I am trying to load a jsp from one spring boot app on a section of a page on another.

I am using JQuery to make a $.ajax() request but from what I can see is that the request isnt even getting to spring filters or controller. The controller response normally when sending from its own browser window.

Error: 
Failed to load http://localhost:8082/settings2: Redirect from 'http://localhost:8082/settings2' to 'http://localhost:8082/settings2/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

2 Applications: settings & settings2. Settings one is trying make an AJAX request to a controller on settings2

settings app page (trying to talk to settings2 app)

```
<script>
$.ajax({url:'http://localhost:8082/settings2',
    type:"POST");
}});
//No success method because chrome console already showing error
</script>
</body>
```

Settings2 configuration app (WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is flagged as depreciated)
    @Configuration
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080", "*")
            .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS").allowedHeaders("*")
            .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Max-Age", "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
                    "Access-Control-Request-Method");
}

}
```

Settings2 websecurity config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors();
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Max-Age", "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
            "Access-Control-Request-Method"));
    // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
    // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
    // not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
    // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/", configuration);
    return source;
}
}
```

settings2 app Cors Filter

```
public class WebSecurityCorsFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
    chain.doFilter(request, res);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
}
```

Settings2 controller
    @CrossOrigin
    @RestController
    public class SettingsController {

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public String getPagePost(HttpServletResponse response) {

    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
public ResponseEntity handle() {
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
 }
```

Settings2 pom

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ddavey</groupId>
<artifactId>settings</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>settings2</name>
<description>Development Team Register Application</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Settings2 app startup logs (Nothing further logged even when the request is sent):

.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
 \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2018-03-15 13:04:07,585 2029 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.s.s.c.a.a.c.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer - Eagerly initializing {webSecurityConfig=com.ddavey.settings.WebSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5891dd83@30260b10}
2018-03-15 13:04:07,724 2168 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@52e26e68, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@624ab72f, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@618df83a, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@1f0c50a, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@174cc9cb, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4fddc7f, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@23710a6c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@231f9098, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@72fafc4, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@17b054e5, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@57cd8b95]

Comment: Why do you redirect *from 'http://localhost:8082/settings2' to 'http://localhost:8082/settings2/'*? That's the same URL.

Comment: I have no idea that's what's happening. I've done nothing to specifically do that.why would that happen?

Comment: Without the Spring Security log it is hard to answer your question. Could you add Spring Security log with `DEBUG` level to your question?

Comment: If your log contains no request, your server is not reached. Do you use a proxy? Add your request and response to your question (for example a screenshot of your dev tool in your browser).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved mine by using the proxy server method. I sent my ajax request to the local server and used the Java back end to pull in the other site and "relay" it back to the ajax request. I was not using SpringBoot but rather a Dynamic web site with servlets which the Ajax calls when through. Worked great and could load five different sites this way in one page and later only used what I wanted from the other pages to build out a new layout look.

Here is a starting point for you which is what I followed [Code to get a Java servlet to act as a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904414/code-to-get-a-java-servlet-to-act-as-a-proxy)