# Rewrite to different context using tuckey urlRewrite

Tags: java, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

We have a web application which runs on root(/) context and we have the content provider which runs on different context (/BK/). We need to map the request from the content provide https://provider.com/BK/ to https://myapp.com/

We don't want the client URL to be updated with this. It's basically a rewrite rather than redirect.

How can I achieve this using tuckey urlrewrite rule? If it can't be done with urlrewrite than can you suggest any other way?

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done using UrlRewriteFilter.  You would need to use a reverse proxy of some sort.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. If not UrlRewriteFilter, can it be done with anything else, like running with multiple contexts

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904414/code-to-get-a-java-servlet-to-act-as-a-proxy